# Is there a way to create a custom image upload handler for CKEditor 4?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, image-uploading, ckeditor4.x

[All the document shows CKEditor 5 supporting custom image uploader handlers.](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html)

In CKEditor 4, you can create custom commands which is fine. But is there a way to expose a custom adapter handler for the existing plugin? I would like to reuse the rest of the code they have in terms of the sizing and captioning -- but I would like to implement my own custom API backend (for example, Imgur)

[It looks like existing libraries are just making entire new plugins.](https://github.com/yfxie/ckeditor-imgur/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/imgur/plugin.js)

I can't use CKEditor 5 since it has only partial support for some of the browsers I need to support.

I could, of course, fork the default image uploading plugin as well to do the work I want. This would be a viable way of going forward.